# get last element of array in input tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have

```
<div id="exp">
  <input type="hidden" name="sum[]" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sum[]" value="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sum[]" value="3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sum[]" value="4" />
</div>
```

And I want in jquery get the value of the last element of the array. I've tried:

> alert(sum[sum.length-1]);

But shows me 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're assuming elements named `sum[]` can be accessed through a global array variable named `sum`. That's not the case. To obtain the last element within a container, you have to query the DOM as jfriend00 demonstrates in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var lastValue = $("#exp input:last").val();
```

This uses a jQuery selector to find the last `input` element that is a child of `#exp` and get its value.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lh7sJ/